# I would like to know how to build gdal for C++ with MinGW、MSYS2.And using the gdal in vs code

Tags: gdal, mingw-w64, msys2

Recently,I am going to try to build GDAL with MinGW.And it must have the precondition that you should build the proj and SQLite first.But I do not know how to add these libraries in the gdal building process.So the MSYS2 shows me the information that it cant find PROJ and SQLite.So I want to know how to add these information to make sure the building process complete.By the way, the GDAL I tried to build is 3.2.3.

I have already use the command ./configure xxx and make.And the make command tell me that it can not find the proj and SQLite.I used to build the GDAL with MSVC in VS.At that moment, I modified the "nmake.opt" to add the information of proj and SQLite.Is this method also useful in the MinGW building process?

Comment: Install prebuilt GDAL with a single command: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdal`. Judging by the huge amount of stuff it installs, building it manually is not easy.

Comment: To know what compiler flags to add to use GDAL, run `pkg-config --libs --cflags gdal`, as you would do with any other library.